# Cython import works once - and then gives a gcc.bat error

Tags: python, c++, windows, gcc, cython

I am writing a Python program in Anaconda/Spyder on a 64-bit Windows 8 machine. I'm getting all the know issues with gcc.bat ("gcc.bat' failed with exit status 1") and I have it fixed - almost. My pyx file (called `testFunc.pyx`) has the following code:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

def funcMatUtility(np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] vecX,
                   np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=1] vecE):
    cdef np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=2] out = \
        np.zeros((len(vecX),len(vecE)),dtype=np.float64)
    for iX, valX in enumerate(vecX):
        for iE, valE in enumerate(vecE):
            out[iX,iE] = valX + valE
    return out
```

I call this function by running the following `py` file in Spyder:

```
import os
import numpy as np

import pyximport
os.environ['CPATH'] = np.get_include()
mingw_setup_args = { 'options': { 'build_ext': { 'compiler': 'mingw32' } } }
pyximport.install(setup_args=mingw_setup_args)

import testFunc

x = testFunc.funcMatUtility(np.array([0.0,1.0,2.0]),np.array([0.0,1.0,2.0,3.0]))
```

Without the line `os.environ['CPATH'] = np.get_include()` I get the gcc.bat error message immediately. Without the setup arguments in `install()` I get another error message: `Unable to find vcvarsall.bat`.

So with these lines I can compile my Cython code, which suggests that this is what I needed to run the `Cython` compiler on my Windows machine in the first place. The problem, however, is that I can only do this once. If want to import it again, for example because I am still developing my code and I only did a test run, I get the gcc.bat error message again (`gcc.bat failed with exit status 1`) unless I close and re-open Spyder. I tried the second import with just the `import` statement (i.e. not importing `pyximport` again), to no avail. What could be the reason that I can only compile the Cython code once?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the problem (and hence, the solution): I need to tell the compiler I'm using `numpy`. I found the explanation here: https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/InstallingOnWindows

So the `py` file should be

```
import numpy
import pyximport
pyximport.install(
    setup_args={"script_args":["--compiler=mingw32"],
    "include_dirs":numpy.get_include()},reload_support=True)
import testFunc
x = testFunc.funcMatUtility(np.array([0.0,1.0,2.0]),np.array([0.0,1.0,2.0,3.0]))
```

The `'include_dirs'` part tells the compiler I'm using `numpy`. This works in Spyder, also in repeated runs.